# Complication with Node.JS on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently trying to develop a website using foundation 5. My problem is a few minutes after installing node.js on my windows laptop, my access is denied by windows whenever I try to run any command of node js, even checking the version of node or npm wont work.

I'm really confused because whenever it's freshly installed, there's no problem whatsoever, but after a few minutes, windows denies my access to any related node js command.

Comment: Could it be the fault of some sort of "security" or similar software that is actively monitoring processes?

Comment: What directory are you installing node.js into?

Comment: Franz, when you ask a question here, you really should check back several times over the next 30 minutes to see if people understood your question or if it needs clarification. StackOverflow works differently than other online forums where you drop a question and then come back the next day. Here's most of your opportunity for people to see your question comes in the first 30 minutes so if your question isn't clarified in that time, then you miss out on most of the people that could help you. And, even those who asked you clarifying questions may just give up if you aren't around to answer.

Comment: Hi sir, I'm really sorry for the lack of clarity in my question and it was like 4am here  (Philippines) when I posted my question. I was installing it into C:Program File (x86), I tried installing it over and over again, but it just denies my access over and over again

Comment: If you want someone specific to see your comment, then put @username at the front of your comment.  That will tell StackOverflow to bring it to their attention.  Otherwise they likely won't see it.  Your issue was that Windows does not allow you to modify certain directories without certain permissions and if it finds you have done so, it will restore the directory from a backup.  That sounds like what you were experiencing.  The usual answer is to install with admin privileges or install in a different directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. just change the installation directory while installing node next time & install it on some other drive....
2. Now go to system properties>Environment variables and add one environment variable with name PATH and value=/installation/directory/of/node
3. Now run any node app with node commands. Hope this will work :)